# C++ error: expected unqualified-id in line 8

Tags: c++

I'm getting error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token in line 8
I have no idea why, my program should do the average of 5 real numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

float void()
{

    float a, b, c, d, e, M;
    cout<<"Introduceti 5 numere de la tastatura: "<<endl;
    cout<<"a=";cin>>a;
    cout<<"b=";cin>>b;
    cout<<"c=";cin>>c;
    cout<<"d=";cin>>d;
    cout<<"e=";cin>>e;
    M=(a+b+c+d+e)/5;
    cout<<"Media aritmetica a celor 5 numere este: "<<M<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Your function does not return any value, so maybe you intended `void float()` :D

Comment: Just tried it, same error

Comment: Sorry, I was kidding. @cad gave you the answer. You can't name a function `void` neither `float`. Those are reserved keywords...

Comment: Time to dig out your old maths book - that's not the average of five numbers.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed it after, about the average that i should divide by 5, that was not a problem

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't name an identifier like a keyword (here `void`). Therefore you need to change the function's name to something else.
2. After adjusting the function name, your function is supposed to return a `float` but you don't return anything at all. Add a `return` statement to the bottom of your function or replace the `float` in the function's prototype with `void` to not return anything at all.
3. Every conforming C++ program on a hosted implementation needs a `main` function. From the C++1y Standard Draft N4296, §3.6.1:

   > A program shall contain a global function called `main`, which is the
   >   designated start of the program. It is implementation-defined whether
   >   a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a `main`
   >   function.

Comment: i changed `void` to `something`
|undefined reference to `WinMain@16'| is my current error
and warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]|

Comment: @MeiloaicaMariusOctavian Great. What about the error message?

Comment: The error message is undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'

Comment: Really a beginner to C++, and i have no ideea what that means honestly

Comment: @MeiloaicaMariusOctavian - So maybe the function should be `int main()`?

Comment: If i'm not asking too much can you please explain your answer

Comment: Thank you @cad for your explicit answer!
Great help

Comment: @MeiloaicaMariusOctavian You are gently invited to accept an answer by clicking on the tick.